# Сохранение изображения

Tags: java, swing

Решил создать программу (мини версию) фотошопа. Все работает, но, у меня есть:

```
public class PhotoshoPanel extends JPanel
```

Как после того как произойдет кокое-то действие, мне достать изображение из объекта JPanel и сохранить его в файл типа jpeg или png?

Comment: вот решение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105915/java-get-an-image-of-a-jpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте объект `BufferedImage` с размерами `JPanel`. 
Получите графический контекст объекта `BufferedImage`. 
Вызовите метод рисования на `JPanel`, передавая графический контекст объекта `BufferedImage`. 
Создайте объект `File` с путём и названием файла исходного файла изображения. 
Запишите `BufferedImage` в файл с помощью `ImageIO.write()`.

Вот пример кода:

```html
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelImageSaver {
    public static void saveAsImage(JPanel panel, String filename) {
        // create a BufferedImage object with the dimensions of the JPanel
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        
        // get the graphics context of the BufferedImage object
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        
        // call the paint method on the JPanel, passing in the graphics context of the BufferedImage object
        panel.paint(g2d);
        
        // create a File object with the path and filename for the output image file
        File output = new File(filename);
        
        try {
            // write the BufferedImage to the file using ImageIO.write()
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
// do something to modify the panel ...
PanelImageSaver.saveAsImage(myPanel, "output.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Отрывки кода:

```
try {
    // retrieve image
    BufferedImage bi = getMyImage();
    File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    //...
}

try {
    // retrieve image
    BufferedImage bi = getMyImage();
    File outputfile = new File("saved.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    //...
}


try {
    // retrieve image
    BufferedImage bi = getMyImage();
    File outputfile = new File("saved.gif");
    ImageIO.write(bi, "gif", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    //...
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html

Comment: Имелось ввиду  - как получить изображение из готовой JPanel'и на которой у меня уже что-то нарисовано. Ответ уже дан. Но и н атом спасибо.